# Methods for flood control on error emails

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp-classic

In most of the websites I develop I add something to notify me by email of any 500 errors.

However, when something goes really wrong, I can get dozens of these error emails (once I got thousands).

So I want to implement some form of flood control. I develop in ASP.NET (C#) and also have some old sites in Classic ASP, but this question is not really about a specific language.

I was thinking of simply storing the last error number and email time in an application variable and if the next error is the same error number and within a certain time frame then do not send an email.

Just wondering what other techniques people are using to accomplish this.

Comment: Do you have control over the sites that could potentially return the 500 response?

Comment: @M.Babcock Yes, I have full control over the websites. I would prefer to do this on a code level rather than on a server level, but welcome all suggestions.

Comment: Are your websites built with ASP.NET or classic?

Comment: @M.Babcock, I have both .NET and Classic sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have decided to go with storing the last error details and time in an application scope variable and if the error is the same as the previous error within a specific time frame I ignore it.

Answer (score 2):

If I were you, I'd try only allowing someone to send an error email if they haven't sent an error email for that type of error in a certain amount of time. If it was a different error, you could allow them to send that one too.

Comment: errors are reported automatically any time they occur, without user intervention.